# FileOutputStream file shown Writable = false

Tags: java, android, fileoutputstream

I am trying to write a bitmap to any of the usual internal folders like 'Pictures, Documents, Download' etc. Below is the file creation I am doing

```
String root = Environment.getRootDirectory().toString();
File myDir = new File(root + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
String Filename = "pic.png";
File fl = new File(myDir + File.separator + Filename);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fl);
```

At the last line, it throws an exception which says 'No such File/Directory'.
If I check fl.canWrite(), it says false!, i.e. fl is not writable.

I even tried to give 'Unrestricted Access' in my testing mobile for this App.

What could be the problem?
What kind of additional things I need to do?

Edit: When I toast, myDir is shown as /system/Pictures.  When I go to File Manager in phone, under my 'Phone storage', 'Pictures' folder is there.  That's a usual folder in Android right ?

Comment: You should check myDir.canWrite() as that file does not exist yet.

Comment: Android version of used device?

Comment: `File fl = new File(myDir, Filename);` and so on saves a bit.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, that must be the reason.  But how to overcome that.   What to do to make it writable?  I expected Pictures folder is not that much restricted!
My Mobile shows Android version 7.0

Comment: @JoopEggen, It was like that earlier, then when I had this problem, I was checking with this syntax.

Comment: What did you do to get permission to read and write storage?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
\\...
File myDir = new File(Environment
     .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
\\...
```

then do a check to confirm directory exist and then proceed to write your file.

Comment: It doesn't work.  Also, Android Studio says (for this method call), as a Privacy Policy Apps can't access such folders!  I have tried creating my own folder in root, ie where our Download, Recording, Music, Pictures etc folders are.  Still .Writable() call says False!
Am I missing any permission ?

Comment: Do you have permission for writing to storage enabled in your Android manifest file?